# How can I get variable from multi dimensional array with php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Screenshot of my array like this;

```
Array(
      [a] => val1 
      [b] => 
           Array(
                 [c]=>68 
          )
)
```

How can I get variable as;

> a=val1
>   c=68

with php using loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('a' => 'val1', 'b' => array('c' => 68));
echo $array['a']; //val1
echo $array['b']['c']; //68
```

To just output all *values* of a multidimensional array:

```
function outputValue($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
      outputValue($value);
      continue;
    }
    echo "$key=$value" . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

The same can be accomplished using [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($value, $key){echo "$key=$value" . PHP_EOL;});
```

Comment: How can I do this with using loop?foreach or for

Comment: @prestack Can you elaborate on what you're using the loop for?

Comment: @prestack Updated with your example output - the code should explain itself, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tim Lytle for your helps. It's very useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

It will take an array (associative) and convert it to query string.

Answer (score 0):

You would use:

```
foreach ($x as $k=>$v)
```

Where `$x` is your array; this will loop through each element of `$x` and assign `$k` the key and `$v` the value.

As an example, here's a code snippet that sets the array and displays it:

```
$x = array('a'=>'val1', 'b'=>'val2');
foreach ($x as $k=>$v) {
    echo "$k => $v<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the PHP function `extract()`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Like this:

```
<?php

$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
               "size"  => "medium",
               "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array);

echo "$color, $size, $shape\n";

?>
```

Comment: `extracts` does not work recursively and will not help in this case. `c` will not be extracted.

Comment: the question was changed after i answered, no mention of multi-dimensional array before.

Answer (score 0):

If you know its maximum one array deep you could use

```
foreach ($myArray as $key=>$val) {
  if (is_array($val) {
    foreach ($val as $key2=>$val2) {
      print $key2.'='.$val2;
    }
  } else {
    print $key.'='.$val;
  }
}
```

if it could be more, use a function

```
function printArray($ar) {
  foreach ($myArray as $key=>$val) {
    if (is_array($val) {
      printArray($val)
    } else {
      print $key.'='.$val;
    }
  }
}

printArray($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract the variables try:

```
<?php
$array = array('a' => 'val1', 'b' => array('c' => 68));

$stack = array($array);
while (count($stack) !== 0) {
    foreach ($stack as $k0 => $v0) {
        foreach ($v0 as $k1 => $v1) {
            if (is_array($v1)) {
                $stack[] = $v1;
            } else {
                $$k1 = $v1;
            }
            unset($k1, $v1);
        }
        unset($stack[$k0], $k0, $v0);
    }
}
unset($stack);
```

This will create `$a` (val1) and `$c` (68) inside of the current variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` + `RecursiveArrayIterator` on `ArrayIterator`

Example Your Current Data

```
$data = array(
  'a' => 'val1',
  'b' => array('c'=>68)
);
```

Solution

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(new ArrayIterator($data)));
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($it as $k=> $var)
{
    printf("%s=%s\n",$k,$var);
}
```

Output

```
a=val1
c=68
```

[See Live Demo PHP 5.1.0 - 5.4.9](http://3v4l.org/YPiFO)