# How can I get variable from my multi dimensional array with php?

Tags: php, arrays

My Array:

```
Array ( 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [balance] => -1 
        [description] => 
        [prices] => Array ( 
            [USD] => Array ( 
                [totalNoFormat] => 58.964939695586 
                [priceNoFormat] => 58.964939695586 
                [saveNoFormat] => 0 
                [total] => $58.96 
                [price] => $58.96 
                [save] => $0.00
            ) 
            [UAH] => Array ( 
                [totalNoFormat] => 500 
                [priceNoFormat] => 500 
                [saveNoFormat] => 0 
                [total] => 500,00 грн. 
                [price] => 500,00 грн. 
                [save] => 0,00 грн. 
            ) 
        )
    ) 
)
```

How I can get value [total] => $58.96 ?

Comment: Wrap the output in `<pre>` tags to get a more readable output. This should be simple enough: `$array[2]['balance']['USD']['total'];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get variable from multi dimensional array with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704503/how-can-i-get-variable-from-multi-dimensional-array-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You array should be in a variable, for my example I will use `$array`, but replace that with the variable your array is in.

```
echo $array[2]['prices']['USD']['total']
```

will echo out the value `$58.96`.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is in $youArr variable then you should print the following:

```
echo $yourArr[2]['prices']['USD']['total'];
```